# Python code creates excel sheets in reverse using xlwings

Tags: python, loops, xlwings

excel creates sheets in reverse order, the loops seem to be fine, the json data that I am using to write it is not in reverse as well.

```
// This part iterates through the each sheet of the workbook
for sheet_data in data['sheets']:
    sheet_id = sheet_data['id']
    sheet_data = sheet_data['data']

    # Create a new sheet in the workbook
    sheet = wb.sheets.add(sheet_id)

    # Loop through each row of data in the sheet
    for i, row_data in enumerate(sheet_data):
        # Loop through each cell in the row and write its value or formula to the corresponding cell in the Excel sheet
        for j, cell_data in enumerate(row_data):
            
            cell = sheet.cells(i+1, j+1)
```

I tried to use reverse method to get the right order but it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can use api to arrange them in the order you desire

```
sheet_name.api.Move(Before=wb.sheets[0].api)
```

That way you can make a small for loop iterating over a list of your sheets and modify it in the order you desire. As a reminder you can get your sheets by:

```
wb.sheet_names
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).